# Simulating a keypress in Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I have been trying to make a program to spam left click because my friend challenged me to click more times than him in 10 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

bool should_click = false;
char in;

int main()
{

    INPUT ip;

    ip.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0x01; //code for left click ^.^
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    while (!should_click)
    {
        cin >> in;
        if (in == 'g')
            should_click = true;
    }
    while (should_click)
    {
        // Press the key
        ip.ki.wVk = 0x01; // virtual-key code for mouse left click
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        // Release the key
        ip.ki.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        Sleep(100);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

When I start the program and press g, Windows fades to black and then to my screensaver and then back to desktop every 100 milliseconds. I tried this with only simulating the keypress once and it did the same (just only once).

Is there a way around this?

PS: No, I can't beat 96 clicks in 10 secs
PPS: I managed to. But I'd still like to know a workaround to make a general spammer.

Comment: `No, I can't beat 96 clicks in 10 secs` And cheating does make it better? Got 91 on the first try, it´s not that hard

Comment: Yeah. Figured out if I use a mouse profile I could get 217. But I'd still like to know if this is possible. I also want to do a spam war with a friend. Is it possible to stop Windows from doing that weird thing?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit adding (Solved) to the title and the solution in body. The question is a question, not an answer. You should post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

[`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) could be used to implement malware.  This is why, ars remarked on MSDN, it it subject to [`UIPI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation).  So you can get rid of this weird behaviour only by running in administrative privilege.

***Edit:*** this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625963.aspx) has a section on UIPI and how to give an application the right to circumvent it.  It involves not just running the code as administrator, but also setting the `UIAccess` attribute in the executable's manifest, and signing the code with a valid certificate.

Comment: UIPI isn't the problem here. UIPI will prevent injecting input to a higher privilege level process. It won't affect input injected into the same privilege level process and it won't corrupt otherwise valid input. The SendInput call will just fail if it would go to a higher privilege process

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT indeed:  you post is the right answer. for this specific piece of code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're sending basically random input to SendInput. Random input -> random output.

To send mouse input you need to use the Input.mi (MOUSEINPUT) version of the INPUT's union, not the ki (KEYBOARDINPUT) version. If you put a break point after setting up your input structures and look at the values in ip.mi you'll probably see out of range x and y and an invalid dwFlags.

If you set up your INPUT structure off of the mi version of the union then you should get reasonable input. You'll also want to fire both a mouse down and a mouse up to get the full click. You can do this in one call to SendInput by setting up an array of INPUT structures:

```
UINT click_at(int x, int y)
{
    INPUT ip[2] = { 0 };

    ip[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    ip[0].mi.dx = x;
    ip[0].mi.dy = y;
    ip[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    ip[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    ip[1].mi.dx = x;
    ip[1].mi.dy = y;
    ip[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

    return SendInput(ARRAYSIZE(ip), ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

If you just want to click wherever the mouse happens to be rather than clicking in a specific place then leave out MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE

Comment: Excellent : with this code, it works as expected ! The fact that the mi.dwFlags (after 2 longs and a dword) is really different from the ki.dwFlags (after 2 words) explains what you mean with garbage !